# Error trying using Flask with Pycharm for an API with the localhost

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to learn how to use RESTapi, so i am in a beginner level.
**the code in Pycharm:**

```
from flask import Flask 
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

STUDENTS = {'1': {'name': 'Mark', 'age': 23, 'spec': 'math'},
  '2': {'name': 'Jane', 'age': 20, 'spec': 'biology'},
  '3': {'name': 'Peter', 'age': 21, 'spec': 'history'},
  '4': {'name': 'Kate', 'age': 22, 'spec': 'science'},}

class StudentsList (Resource):
    def get(self):
        return STUDENTS
    def post(self):
        parser.add("name")
        parser.add("age")
        parser.add("spec")
        args = parser.parse_args()
        student_id = int(max(STUDENTS.keys())) + 1
        student_id = '%i' % student_id
        STUDENTS[student_id ] = {
            "name" : args["name"],
            "age" : args["age"],
            "spec" : args["spec"],
        }
        return STUDENTS[student_id], 201

api.add_resource(StudentsList, '/students/')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I am running Flusk on PyCharm and when i click on the localhost link on the console http://127.0.0.1:5000/, i get a not found error. I searched in internet, but i couldn't find a solution. I think, i do not understand completely, how the localhost works and how i can reach it and also if i have to create it first or something

Comment: The api has only one url `/students/`.  But you're requesting `/`, which does not exist.

Comment: @JohnGordon can you explain it a bit more, how i had to do it. Because i am not very familiar with apis and that was my try for my first. The tutorial i have seen, had exactly the same code and for them had worked and a localhost was available for them.

Answer (score 0):

http://127.0.0.1:5000/students

This is the only url defined by you.
`http://127.0.0.1:5000/`  This url does not exist